# Why a word in memory always contains 2^n number of bytes?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

I don't understand why a word always contains bytes in power of 2 . Why it can't contain 5 bytes or 6 bytes ?

Comment: ease of address calculation, power of 2 means that simple bit shifting is enough to calculate byte addresses etc.

Comment: There are some instructions on some architectures that load or store a non-power-of-2 size.  e.g. x87's internal 80-bit floating format can be loaded/stored with a special version of [FLD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FLD.html) and [FSTP](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FST:FSTP.html).  x86 memory-indirect far jumps in 32-bit mode load 2+4 bytes.  But these are the exceptions, not the rule, for the reason Isu stated.

Answer (score 2):

This has not always been the case. There have been machines in the past that have 12 bits (the PDP-8) 18 bits (the PDP-7) 36 bits (the PDP-10) or even 60 bits (the CDC 6600)

Even today there are machines with odd sizes. The PIC 16xxxx family by Microchip stores intructions in 14 bit words while the 24xxxx series uses 24 bit instructons. These are however, specialized, embedded chips, not general purpose machines.

For the most part though, things moved to powers of two. A big push for this was the old IBM 360 which introduced the now familiar (if somewhat dated) 32 bit word containing 4 eight bit bytes.

This combination of a power of two word size and a power of two number of bytes per word made addressing of both integers/pointers and characters simple and efficient.

Modern machines have simply updated this to 64 bit words with 8 eight bit bytes per word, retaining this useful advantage.

Comment: Do any of those examples you mention have byte-addressable memory?  If memory is only word-addressable, then address calculations never have to scale by the number of bits in a word, or number of octets in a word.  (e.g. the machine might just have a 12-bit memory bus?)

Comment: Most machines back then where word address machines. The PDP-10 however could break up a word into 6 six bit "bytes" or 5 seven bit ones with a wasted bit or 4 eight bit bytes with 4 wasted bits or 4 nine bit bytes. Special instructions where used to do this and it was up to the programmer to handle word boundaries and other addressing concerns. In fact, the word could be subdivided into any number of variable bit fields so long as they fit in a 36 bit word.

Comment: Hmm, so I guess if you wanted the Nth character in a string, you'd have to divide N by some non-power-of-2 to get the word address that contained the character you were looking for :/  I'd been thinking that word-addressable memory would mostly avoid having to scale by non-power-of-2 factors, but maybe not for software trying to make efficient use of memory.

Comment: Yes, you had to do a lot of math just to find a character. I've had similar problems with the PIC 24xxx series with placing strings in it 24 bit memory without wasting every third byte.